# Rails gem with Railtie requires server restart to load changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm developing a ruby gem with a Rails engine and railtie in it.  I've made good progress but one of my biggest pain points is having to restart the Rails server every time I make a change to the gem for testing.

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'my_gem', :source => '~/apps/my_gem'
```

I've tried adding the path to the autoloads, with no success:

#### config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W( ~/apps/my_gem )
```

I'm guessing the issue is that the Railtie in the gem is only loaded when the server starts.  Is there a way to dynamically load my gem so that I don't have to keep restarting the server when I change some code?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you can use [shotgun](http://rubygems.org/gems/shotgun). It works with any rack server by reloading it with every new request. After you have install it, run the following command inside your rails app's directory:

```
$ shotgun
```

Pretty simple! Also, you can use it with [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), like so:

```
$ shotgun my_website.rb
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: this looks promising, I'm going to give it a shot and report back.

Comment: Alright, here's what I found, shotgun does what it says it does, it reloads the app on every request, which obviously slows things down.  I can live with that, but now I'm missing the stack traces I need to debug.  I tried the warn option, which gave lots of warnings, but still no stacktrace.  I gave you a vote up, but this still isn't quite what I'm looking for.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I use it regularly with Sinatra and it gives me perfect stack traces; I wonder why it's not working for you. Maybe it has something to do with rails... I'll look into this